# What does "open sentence" mean in philosophy?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-mind

I'm reading some books on theory of knowledge and philosophy of mind. In those readings, notion of "open sentences" are used for certain extension, for example by [Davidson](http://fitelson.org/proseminar/davidson.pdf).

Question: what does open sentence mean in philosophy?

Comment: Is there any chance I could persuade you to share a little more about your context? What books are you reading?

Comment: @JosephWeissman Davidson's mental events. And D.W.Hamlyn's The theory of knowledge.

Comment: @Darae-Uri, more context would still be useful... can you edit your question with a passage for context? Also, in general, when someone asks for clarification, edit your question so that others who come across your question don't have to figure it out from the comment thread.

Comment: Yes, please provide one or two quotations involving "open sets", from both sources.

Comment: I found no "open sets" in Mental Events, there are plenty of "open sentences" but no "open sets" http://fitelson.org/proseminar/davidson.pdf

Comment: @Conifold oh that's what i meant. In that sense, what "open" means?  Since I read Davidson few months ago, I couldn't remember it exactly.

Comment: I discovered the same ie 'open sentences'; which confused me somewhat.

Comment: What of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_sentence do you not understand? These kind of definition questions are generally discouraged, because they're answered well elsewhere (like Wikipedia).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An open sentence is a sentence featuring a free variable. They are sometimes called open formulas.

For example, '*x* is green' is an open sentence, whereas 'Sam is green' is not.

Open sentences can be thought of as expressing a (possibly complex) property.

(I've checked and this is the sense being used in the Davidson paper mentioned.)